# How to use the OAuth boilerplate in WDC 3.0?

Tags: tableau-api, taco

I am building a custom connector for Tableau Desktop using WDC 3.0 SDK. I have used OAuth boilerplate,the first part of authentication process seems to go smoothly(it redirects me to the login page and all), but when it is tries to exchange authcode with access token following error is displayed.

An error occurred while communicating with data source 'sample'

Authentication failed.

Error Code: 84223ADA

400 Bad Request

POST

{

"Error": "Incorrect or missing content type"

}

The documentation doesn't say anything about adding a header or body for token URL. How can I solve this?

I have tried looking for the files where the auth flow is implemented but couldn't find anything.